# How do I count the number of characters in a UITextField in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios8, uitextfielddelegate

In my code I'm using one of the UITextFieldDelegate methods to detect when a textfield has been left so I can do a check and alert the user.

The first check is the amount of characters they have type into the textfield.

**Here is my code:**

```
override func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    if textField == self.signUpView.usernameField {
        if textField.text.length // this doesn't work
    }

    if textField == self.signUpView.passwordField {

    }

    if textField == self.signUpView.emailField {

    }

}
```

How is this done in swift?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get "type string does not conform to protocol _Collection" when I use the example in the link above.

Comment: What did you try? `countElements(textField.text!)` should work.

Comment: Missed the exclamation. Will delete question